# How to make a stage depend on another stage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a YAML file as below. Let’s say the *.md file is committed, the build does not work, but the test works. Here how can I make the test depend on the build? Like if the build doesn’t work, the test shouldn’t work.

Thanks in advance.

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Build is running"
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - requirements.txt
      - ./configs/*
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Test is running"
    - echo "$CI_JOB_STAGE"
  dependencies:
   - build
```

Comment: [MrTux01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15142882/mrtux01) your test stage is running because you have specified to only create the build job using the [only keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except). The test job, that is part of the test stage, will run so long as all previous jobs from the previous stage have finished without error. If there are no jobs created in the build stage, the test stage will always run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be what [`stages` defines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages)

> Use `stages` to define stages that contain groups of jobs.
> `stages` is defined globally for the pipeline.
> Use `stage` in a job to define which stage the job is part of.
>
> The order of the `stages` items defines the execution order for jobs:
>
> - Jobs in the same stage run in parallel.
> - Jobs in the next stage run after the jobs from the previous stage complete successfully.
>
> For example:
>
> ```yaml
> stages:
>  - build
>  - test
>  - deploy
> ```
>
> - All jobs in build execute in parallel.
> - If all jobs in build succeed, the test jobs execute in parallel.
> - If all jobs in test succeed, the deploy jobs execute in parallel.
> - If all jobs in deploy succeed, the pipeline is marked as passed.
>
> If any job fails, the pipeline is marked as failed and jobs in later stages do not start.
> Jobs in the current stage are not stopped and continue to run.

So, in your case:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
```

`test` won't run if `build` fails.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you. But here is a main problem. Build stage runs when Dockerfile changes. If Dockerfile does not change, test stage still runs.

Comment: @MrTux01 Is it possible, for testing, to add the the same `only: changes:` condition on `test` stage

Comment: Yes this approach is ok for me. But i just want to know if there is a right way.

Comment: @MrTux01 I don't know of another way. Let's wait if other users might write a different answer here.